# Twitter type load data from database

Tags: php, ajax

So basically I need something similar that twitter has - when user scrolls down to the bottom of the page, new information from database automatically loads. Any suggestions how to create it or any examples? I know it can be done with AJAX, but could you please show a example, or a sample code?

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) plugin.

Comment: as far as I understood it's only for wordpress, but I'm making a site on CodeIgniter MVC.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. [Here](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/) is the correct one.

Comment: Hello, thank you, please write answer, I'll accept yours ;)!

Comment: Accept @Alexander's - he's actually given the same link I did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called Infinite Scrolling (or [Endless Scrolling](http://uipatternfactory.com/p=endless-scrolling/)). I think the most widespread solution is using Paul Irish's [Infinite Scroll jQuery plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/). Also, you can find related information, documentation and demos in the [Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com) page.